# Laravel eloquent how to create relationship if it not exists?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to find or create user->settings relationship. I tried to use `$this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->withDefault();`, but this method returns new relationship while need I to create and store relationship with default values in DB and then return it. Is there any way to do so?

route

```
 Route::get('settings', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user()->load('settings');
        });
```

relation

```
 public function settings()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->withDefault( // I want to save row with this values in DB if it not exists and return it after
            [
            'backup_password' => '',
            'backup_email' => '',
            'codeword' => '',
            'security_notifications' => 0,
            'password_changed_at' => null,
            'two_step_authentication' => 0
        ]);
}
```

UPD

I solved this problem like this, but I'm pretty sure that there is a better and cleaner solution

```
if(!($this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->exists())) {
            $settings = new UserSettings();
            $settings->user_id = Auth::id();
            $settings->backup_password = '';
            $settings->backup_email = '';
            $settings->codeword = '';
            $settings->security_notifications = 0;
            $settings->password_changed_at = null;
            $settings->two_step_authentication = 0;
            $settings->save();
        }
        return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner way would be for example

```php
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->withDefault(function ($settings, $user) {
        $settings->fill([
            'backup_password' => '',
            'backup_email' => '',
            'codeword' => '',
            'security_notifications' => 0,
            'password_changed_at' => null,
            'two_step_authentication' => 0,
        ]);

        $user->settings()->save($settings);
    });
}
```

Or even better if your default attributes are constant

In your `UserSettings` model

```php
/**
     * The model's default values for attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [
            'backup_password' => '',
            'backup_email' => '',
            'codeword' => '',
            'security_notifications' => 0,
            'password_changed_at' => null,
            'two_step_authentication' => 0,
        ];
```

```php
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->withDefault(function ($settings, $user) {
        $user->settings()->save($settings);
    });
}
```

Comment: This snippet is creating the corresponding relationship model $settings on every request!

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have a separate method on the user model which calls the existing relationship or creates a new relationship and saves it to the database. For example:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->withDefault(
        UserSettings::defaultAttributes()
    );
}

// This checks to see if the relationship already exists within
// the database and if it does not then creates a new relationship,
// saves it to the database with the default attributes which you
// could make on the UserSettings model and then returns the user Model
// with the new settings.
public function loadOrCreateSettings()
{
    if ( ! $this->settings()->exists()) {
        $this->settings()->create(UserSettings::defaultAttributes());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Doing it this way means your routes are cleaner and you are letting the User model handle the logic.

```
Route::get('settings', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user()->loadOrCreateSettings();
});
```